# Magento bundle product price not visible

Tags: magento

> I am creating new products bundle I got tutorial about how to create
>   **Magento** **bundle** I found that the current version I'm working on 1.6 the
>   price not visible as the tutorial shown ..

[image: My current bundle price]

[image: The bundle price shown in tutorial]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below price attribute option, if not apply then apply to bundle product also.

```
Apply TO:Bundle Product
```

select bundle product as well, Clear cache then try.